# Linq to XML dynamic XML Decendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm parsing a lot of XML files using Linq to XML synatx, everything works when I try to access top level elements

```
var indexroot = (from element in prodcutDocument.Root.Descendants("indexroot")
                        select new
                        {
                            model = (string)element.Element("MODEL"),
                        }).FirstOrDefault()
```

The problem occurs when I need to access lower level childs of that document I tried:

```
var indexroot = (from element in prodcutDocument.Root.Descendants("indexroot")
                        select new
                        {
                            ddName = (string)element.Descendants("DD_NAME").Elements("name").First();
                            }).FirstOrDefault()
```

and

```
var indexroot = (from element in prodcutDocument.Root.Descendants("indexroot").Descendants("DD_NAME")
                             select new
                             {
                                 ddName = (string)element.Element("name")
                             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Sadly none of that works and i get same error "Sequence contains no elements". And one more thing sometimes the XML document contains those tags and sometimes not is something like this enough for handling this case?

```
var indexroot = (from element in prodcutDocument.Root.Descendants("indexroot").Descendants("DD_NAME")
                             select new
                             {
                                 ddName = (string)element.Element("name") ?? "-"
                             }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Edit: 
I don't think is possible to paste short version of XML that would be simple, so here's full version: http://pastebin.com/uDkP3rnR and for the code example:

```
XDocument prodcutDocument = XDocument.Load(this.ServerPATHData + file); 

var indexroot = (from element in prodcutDocument.Root.Descendants("indexroot")
            select new
            {
                modelis = (string)element.Element("MODELIS"),
                T2918_0 = (string)element.Descendants("dd_DARBINIS_GRAFIKAS_SPEC").First()
            }).FirstOrDefault();

writeTxt.WriteLine("modelis: " + indexroot.modelis);
writeTxt.WriteLine("T2979_0" + indexroot.T2918_0);
```

Comment: It should be fine. Please provide a short but *complete* example (XML and code) which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In examining the sample XML that you posted on PasteBin, it appears to me that the elements that you mention appear only once. To access them, you can simply specify a path to each as follows:

```cs
XElement indexroot = document.Root.Element("indexroot");
XElement modelis = indexroot.Element("MODELIS");
XElement dd_dgs = indexroot.Element("dd_DARBINIS_GRAFIKAS_SPEC");

XElement voltageuv = dd_dgs.Element("VoltageUV");

string t2979_0 = (string)voltageuv.Element("T2979_0");
string t2861_60 = (string)voltageuv.Element("T2861_60");
string t2757_121 = (string)voltageuv.Element("T2757_121");
```

(Note that you may need to check for `null` if there is a chance that any of the elements you are trying to access may not be present. Without doing so, you'll encounter a `NullReferenceException`.)

Here is a snippet of the XML that you posted to give context to the above code:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<PDB>
  <indexroot>
    <ed_BENDRA_MAKS_SUV_GALIA>1.45</ed_BENDRA_MAKS_SUV_GALIA>
    <ed_BENDRA_MAKS_SROVE>6.48</ed_BENDRA_MAKS_SROVE>
    <TIPAS>1</TIPAS>
    <MODELIS>RIS 2500 HW EC 3.0</MODELIS>
    <dd_DARBINIS_GRAFIKAS_SPEC>
      <VoltageUV>
        <T2979_0>229,42</T2979_0>
        <T2861_60>227,98</T2861_60>
        <T2757_121>228,97</T2757_121>
      </VoltageUV>
      <CurrentIA>
        <T2979_0>2,56</T2979_0>
        <T2861_60>2,63</T2861_60>
        <T2757_121>2,72</T2757_121>
      </CurrentIA>
    </dd_DARBINIS_GRAFIKAS_SPEC>
  </indexroot>
</PDB>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change:

```
element.Descendants("dd_DARBINIS_GRAFIKAS_SPEC").First()
```

to this:

```
element.Descendants("dd_DARBINIS_GRAFIKAS_SPEC").FirstOrDefault() ?? "-"
```

Comment: I used T2918_0 = (string)element.Descendants("dd_DARBINIS_GRAFIKAS_SPEC").Elements("VoltageUV").Elements("T2979_0").FirstOrDefault() ?? "-" because I need to get lower level child, it helped with the error, but the variable is empty.

Comment: @user2358309 If it's empty, then there are no `T2979_0` elements obviously. Also, this approach is not safe - what if there will be no `VoltageUV` element? This is getting too big - create a separate method, that will handle all cases and return the proper content for the `T2918_0` property.